# An Implementation of Double-Array Trie

Tags: c, trie

I'm trying to understand and use this [Double-Array Trie implementation](http://linux.thai.net/~thep/datrie/datrie.html). However,i can seem to understand the analogy between the theoretical implementation they present and the code.
To be precise, the following is the main Trie structure used:

```
struct _Trie {
AlphaMap   *alpha_map;
DArray     *da;
Tail       *tail;

Bool        is_dirty;
};
```

If anyone has used this implementation, can you please provide a high level explanation of the use of the following structures and the relation to the double array concept regarding base and check arrays. Expecially the AlphaMap.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

`libdatrie` translates unicode characters to compact internal representation; you have to define a list of allowed ranges while creating a trie. `alpha_map` is a linked list of character ranges.

`da` is a Double-Array structure. It contains `base` and `check` arrays.

`tail` is a data structure used for storing non-branching suffixes (see "Suffix Compression").

`is_dirty` is a flag that is set to TRUE if the trie is not stored to disk yet or if it was changed after loading from disk.